# Problem training unigram tagger on nps_chat corpus

Tags: nlp, nltk

At first I tried training the tagger on tagged sentences, but unlike with 
Brown, the nps chat corpus doesn't seem to take the tagged_sents() method. 
So then I tried training on tagged words and Python returned the error 
message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in
> <module> 
>     unigram_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(training_set)    File
> "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 287, in 
> __init__ 
>     backoff, cutoff, verbose)    File
> "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 270, in 
> __init__ 
>     self._train(train, cutoff, verbose)    File
> "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 181, in 
> _train 
>     tokens, tags = zip(*sentence)  ValueError: need more than 1 value
> to unpack
```

I suspect the issue has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to 
train the tagger on tagged words rather than sentences, but what's the 
solution to this if nps chat doesn't take the tagged_sents method? And why 
doesn't it accept that method?  Please advise.

Comment: Training the tagger works with the `tagged_posts()` method.